# How do I add commas in a string of values

Tags: php

I have an array and I'm trying to concatenate some values of this array. Currently, `$all` looks like: "AmazonSonySmashwordsBN" (see code below)

How do I make it look like: "Amazon, Sony, Smashwords, BN"

I understand how to concatenate. My problem is, I don't want a comma if one of the $bookcategory strings is empty.

```
$book = array("18"=>'BN', "19"=>'Amazon', "20"=>'Sony', "21"=>'Kobo', "22"=>'Smashwords', "23"=>'Apple', "24"=>'Android');

$bookcategory1 = $book[$catagory1];
$bookcategory2 = $book[$catagory2];
$bookcategory3 = $book[$catagory3];
$bookcategory4 = $book[$catagory4];


$all = $bookcategory1 . $bookcategory2 . $bookcategory3 . $bookcategory4; 

echo $all;
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$bookcategory1.', '.$bookcategory2` isnt good enough for you?

Comment: First you have to break apart the `$all` into an array, and then put the elements of the array back together with `join()`.  The tough part is splitting apart `$all` because you haven't said what the rules are for breaking it apart.

Comment: So you seem to understand concatenation using `.`  and you seem to understand how to create strings within quotes.  You are not bale to make the logical leap to figure out how to concatenate you variable values with string values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can join your array with the [`implode` function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php):

```
echo implode(', ', array_values($book));
```

If you want to display some elements of your array only (it seems you only show 4 categories here), reduce your array to 4 elements (or create a new one with these values) and use implode.

Comment: always prefer the implode. +1

Comment: A space can be added after the comma, too, so it's a bit more readable

Comment: @aynber well, well, details... You're a little stickler, no? :p

Comment: Depends on my mood. LOL :-D

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to go about it:

```
$all = "$bookcategory1, $bookcategory2, $bookcategory3, $bookcategory4";
```

The double quotes allows the variables to be processed, instead of just echoing out the variable names.

OR

```
$all = $bookcategory1 .", ". $bookcategory2 .", ". $bookcategory3 .", ". $bookcategory4;
```

Comment: Yes. I understand how to concatenate. My problem is, I don't want a comma if one of the $bookcategory strings is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $a . "," . $b - but here's a better way... it works a lot like using variables in a shell script:

```
    $a = "this";
    $b = "that";
    $c = "other thing";
    echo "${a},${b},${c}\n";
```

The output is:

> this,that,other thing

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$str = implode(', ', array_values($book));
//=> BN, Amazon, Sony, Kobo, Smashwords, Apple, Android
```

Comment: this is just like **Maxime Lorant**'s answer, but will be more confusing for a beginner due to a lack of echo

Comment: @abstr: Only difference is that I posted before (though I am happy that other answer got so many upvotes as I have already exceeded my rep limit for the day).

Answer (score 1):

```
$all = $bookcategory1 . $bookcategory2 . $bookcategory3 . $bookcategory4;
```

should be:

```
$all = $bookcategory1 . ", " . $bookcategory2 . ", " . $bookcategory3 . ", " . $bookcategory4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could just do as this will format all to what you wanted.

```
$all = $bookcategory1 . ", " . $bookcategory2 . ", " . $bookcategory3 . ", "  $bookcategory4;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the extra comma if an array value is empty, for example the following array:

```
$book = array("18" => '',
              "19" => 'Amazon',
              "20" => 'Sony',
              "21" => 'Kobo',
              "22" => 'Smashwords',
              "23" => 'Apple',
              "24" => 'Android'
             );
```

Normal concatenation with `$book[0] . ", " . $book[1] ...` or `implode(", ",$book)` the output will start with an extra comma (`, Amazon, Sony`) because it's adding the blank value as well. To skip the blank, you'll need to filter the value out:

```
$all = implode(", ",array_filter($book));

echo $all;
  // Amazon, Sony, Kobo, Smashwords, Apple, Android
```

http://codepad.org/CNvhYYBm